# Half normals are wrong

Tags: opengl, normals, 3d-modelling, sculpture

I'm using a program called sculptris to create models in Wavefront OBJ format. I just created my first couple models and am now trying to import them into an OpenGL scene. I've never written an object loader before tonight but I'm pretty sure I got the parsing of the OBJ file right. Unfortunately, when I add lighting, it seems that the normals on half of the model are incorrect. Without lighting, the model is textured and colored correctly and looks perfect. With lighting the image looks like this...

[image]

If half the model is correct, I'm pretty sure there is nothing wrong with my OBJ parsing. Therefore sculptris must only have the normals correct for half the model (probably something resulting from the symmetry of the sculpting). If anyone's familiar with the program, know what I'm doing wrong. For those that are just familiar with OBJ in general, is there something I don't know about OBJ involving duplicate normals (which there are because the model is left-right symmetrical)?

Comment: I recommend creating a very simple model, like a cube, where you can easily understand if the data you're trying to import is correct or not.  It's pretty common for 3D modeling programs to imperfectly support exporting to a number of formats.  In general, only the native import/export format can be relied on to faithfully reproduce what you see in the package itself.

Comment: I'll try doing that tomorrow...good suggesstion! Also, OBJ is the only export format the program supports. Hope they didn't get that wrong...haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This model is symmetrical. So there's a fairly good chance that you created it by creating half of it and then mirroring it. In many modelling applications, mirroring inverts the normal and changes the winding order. So you will have to select those faces and flip their normals.

Comment: I got everything working. I imported the OBJ into blender where there is a simple button to fix all normals and smooth them. thanks!